# cypress custom find command

Tags: testing, cypress

I have a custom command that gets me my elements with the `data-cy` attribute.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("getById", (id) => {
    cy.get(`[data-cy=${id}]`)
})
```

everything's working fine.

Now it would be nice if I had the same with find. It would be looking like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("findById", { prevSubject: true }, (subject, id) => {
    cy.wrap(subject).find(`[data-cy=${id}]`)
})
```

The problem there is that cypress throws an error with this code:

```js
cy.root().then((root) => {
    if(root.findById("...").length) {
     ...
   }
})
```

The error is `"root.findById" is not a function`.

Can you help me write that custom command correctly?

Answer (score 6):

The basic problem is that `subject` passed in to the command is already wrapped, so just chain the `find()` from it. Also you need to return the result to use it in the test.

**Custom command**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("findById", { prevSubject: true }, (subject, id) => {
  return subject.find(`[data-cy=${id}]`)
})
```

The next problem is you can't mix 'ordinary' js code with Cypress commands, so the returned value must be accessed from a `.then()`.

**Spec**

```js
describe('...', () => {
  it('...', () => {
    cy.visit('app/find-by-id.html')
    cy.root().findById('2').then(el => {
       console.log('found', el, el.length)
       expect(el.length).to.eq(2)
    })
  })
})
```

**Html used to test the test (app/find-by-id.html)**

```html
<div>
  <div data-cy="1"></div>
  <div data-cy="2"></div>
  <div data-cy="2"></div>
  <div data-cy="3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [@Richard Matsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54523181/1860149), you might want to add some log into your command, so that it appears well in your cypress log, just as if you had used `.find(...)` directly:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
  "findByTestId",
  {
    prevSubject: ["element"],
  },
  (
    subject: Cypress.Chainable<HTMLElement>,
    testId: string,
    options?: Partial<
      Cypress.Loggable &
        Cypress.Timeoutable &
        Cypress.Withinable &
        Cypress.Shadow
    >
  ) => {
    const $el = subject.find(`[data-testid=${testId}]`, options);
    Cypress.log({
      $el: $el as any,
      name: "findByTestId",
      message: testId,
    });
    return $el;
  }
);
```